# Append new column to csv (from url) before writing

Tags: python

In trying to extract some csv files from a url, I use the **numbers** list below as identifiers to extract the csv files. For each csv file after extraction, I would like to include an additional column called 'identifier', whose row values will be the number variable it represents, before writing the csv. How can I achieve this?

```
numbers = ['00014798','00019323','00020949']
      
     for number in numbers:
            csv_url = *url_goes_+_number_+_here*
            print(csv_url)
            req = requests.get(csv_url)
            url_content = req.content
            csv_file = open(number + '.csv', 'wb')               
            csv_file.write(url_content)
            csv_file.close()
```

Comment: Did you try to modify `req.content` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate `number` with the content:

```
url_content = f"{number},{req.content}"
with open(number+'.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_file.write(url_content)
```